# How to add more fields to custom User in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, post, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to pass more fields to my user when it gets registered but no luck. so far the only thing I can get in `validated_data` is username and password. How can I get data such as `is_doctor` there? Or perhaps I'm looking at the wrong place.

the fields do get created in the User table with their defaults, I can't override them with `true`, though.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_secretary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'is_doctor', 'is_secretary', 'is_patient') 
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # validated_data only contains username and password. I wish it could have 'is_doctor'
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Below is JavaScript in the frontend trying to create new user in the api

```
  function registerUserAndDoctor(values) {
    const credentials = {
      ...values //contains 'is_doctor: true'
    }
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/user/`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("res USER>>", res);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you've imported your custom User model in the file where your UserSerializer is, and not e.g. the Django default User? At a quick glance I don't see why this would otherwise fail (if you're absolutely sure you're sending the right data).

Comment: Did you override the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting? You can read more on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: This is how I'm importing it in my serializers file: ```from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model | User = get_user_model()```.

Comment: I have overriden the AUTH_USER_MODEL with ```AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myAppName.User'```